# Tabs showing on Login Page in Xamarin Forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app that uses Shell and the home page of the app happens to have tabs defined in the Shell -- see below:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Home">
   <FlyoutItem.Icon>
       <FontImageSource
           FontFamily="MISHRP"
           Glyph="{StaticResource HomeIcon}"
           Color="White" />
   </FlyoutItem.Icon>
   <Tab Title="My Feed">
      <ShellContent Route="MyFeed" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MyFeedFeed}"/>
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Card">
      <ShellContent Route="PersonalCard" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:PersonalCard}"/>
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Cart">
      <ShellContent Route="Cart" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Cart}"/>
   </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

In the `OnStart()` method of `App.xaml.cs`, I check to see if the user is authenticated and if not, I send user to a separate `Login` page with the following code:

```
protected override async void OnStart()
{
    // Check to see if token has expired or missing
    var tokenExpiration = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("token_expiration");
    if(tokenExpiration == null)
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(LoginPage));

    // Some more logic here...
}
```

This works fine but when I get to the `Login` page, I see the tabs defined in Shell.

I already use `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"` on `Login` page which successfully hides the nav bar but NOT the tabs.

How do I make sure no tabs will be visible on `Login` page?

Comment: try please ```await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(LoginPage)}");``` https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20201030-LoginFlowInXamarinFormsShell.html

Comment: It didn't work. Still seeing the tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was add `Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"` to the `Login` XAML. See below:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.LoginPage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
             Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False">
```